# I don't know how to fix the following error; RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1' and 'Thread-2'

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I'm a beginner at coding, and its my very first time using threads. Threads was the only solution I could find for my project. In the project I'm supposed to show on the app which sensor is vibrating, and to do that i drew 4 circles around to represent the sensor. So sensor 1 would be bytearray(b'\x03'), sensor 2 would be bytearray(b'\x04') and so on. What i would want is for the color of sensor 1 to change when the characteristic value is bytearray(b'\x03').

Currently using python 3.9 to create an app that connects through bluetooth with an arduino nano 33 iot, and i want to be able to read the characteristic every .3 second, and based on the value its supposed to change the color of a canvas drawing. My intention here is to have the while loop running in the background reading the characteristic value every .3 second. And on my main screen, based on the value that's read, for an example, if it reads bytearray(b'\x03') it supposed to change the color of one drawing on the screen. (That's why the if statement, so that condition to change color would replace the 'print("changed color")). Also there will be multiple sensors to check bytearray(b'\x03') through bytearray(b'\x10'), so i dont know if an if statement is the best to use, so if you have a better suggestion please let me know.

```
def background():
    async def run(address):
        async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
            await client.get_services()
            while True:
                value = await client.read_gatt_char(r_characteristic)
                if await client.read_gatt_char(r_characteristic):
                    time.sleep(.3)
                    print("Read Value: {0}".format(value))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def foreground():
    async def run(address):
        async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
            await client.get_services()
            value = await client.read_gatt_char(r_characteristic)
            if await client.read_gatt_char(r_characteristic) == bytearray(b'\x03'):
                print("changed color")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(run(address))
    loop.run_forever()


b = threading.Thread(target=background)
f = threading.Thread(target=foreground)

b.start()
f.start()
```

However when i run it, it send me an error back as shown below;

```
raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
     raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
 RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
 RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: It is somewhat unusual to combine threads and async.  Are you sure this is right approach?  Nothing is going to run in your background thread, because you never call `run()`.

Comment: thanks for the help, but since i need to connect through bluetooth to the arduino first so the while loop can read the characteristic value, my best approach was to use async. how would you recommend me to write the while loop that can connect and populate the values in the background? i basically want to use those values to change the canvas color on a kv file that i have.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines at the end of your code:

```
b.join()
f.join()
```

Might work, might not work, but as Tim Roberts has correctly said, combining threads and async is rather unusual and you might need to refactor your code.

Comment: what would be the best approach for me to do the while loop then? because the reason i'm using async is to read the characteristic value of an arduino nano 33 iot that the app is connect through bluetooth. So technically for the while loop to work it has to be connected to the arduino. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: have you actually tried b.join and f.join at the end?